# pattern matching in java using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a pattern to match this `"LA5@10.232.140.133@Po6"` and one more `"LA5@10.232.140.133@Port-channel7"` expression in Java using regular expression.

Like we have \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} for IP address validation.

Can we have the pattern like below? Please suggest--

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]@\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}@Po\d[1-9]
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]@\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}@Port-channel\d[1-9]
```

Thanks in advance.

==============================

In my program i have,

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class ptternmatch {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w\\w\\w@\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}@*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("LA5@10.232.140.133@Port-channel7");
        boolean b = false;
        System.out.println("Pattern is " + m.pattern());
        while(b = m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start() + " " + m.group());
    }
    }
}
```

But i am getting compilation error with the pattern.--> Invalid escape sequence
The sequence will be like a ->a 3 character word of digit n letter@ipaddress@some text..

Comment: What is the actual question?  Which parts of the examples are you having trouble matching? Which parts are variable and which parts are static in your expected data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to validate the IP address, then you need something a little bit more involved than `\d{1,3}`.  Also, keep in mind that for Java string literals, you need to escape the `\` with `\\` so you end up with a single backslash in the actual regex to escape a character such as a period (`.`).

Assuming the `LA5@` bit is static and that you're fine with either `Po` or `Port-channel` followed by a digit on the end, then you probably need a regex along these lines:

```
LA5@(((2((5[0-5])|([0-4][0-9])))|(1[0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9]))|(1[0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]?)@Po(rt-channel)?[1-9]
```

(Bracketing may be wonky, my apologies)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `matcher.find()` and, if it is true, the groups to capture the information. Take a look a the tutorial here:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

You would need to wrap the necessary parts int parentheses - e.g. `(\d{1,3})`. If you wrap all 4, you will have 4 groups to access.

Also, take a look at this tutorial

- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2001/jw-0713-regex.html?page=3

It's a very good tutorial, I think this one would explain most of your questions.

To match the second of your strings:

- LA5@10.232.140.133@Port-channel7

you can use something like:

```
\w{2}\d@\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}@[a-zA-Z\-]+\d
```

This depends on what you want to do, so the regex might change.

Comment: I think, he is looking for the exact Java regExp pattern to find those example strings.

Comment: @Andreas_D I misunderstood it the first time... Thank you!